# как сравнить символ в алфавитном порядке?

Tags: javascript

```
  function isAlphabet(letters) {
  if (letters.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < letters.length - 1; i++) {
    if (letters[i].localeCompare(letters[i + 1]) < 0) {
      continue;
    }
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Мне нужно сравнить каждый символ со следующим, только в порядке алфавита.
Думаю, что нужно использовать localeCompare, только как я понимаю - он сравнивает елемент со следующим не по алфавиту, а будто бы по порядку возростания, потому у меня будет true в строке 'abd', ведь d больше b, но мне нужно false, так как строка не по алфавиту.

Пример правильного результата: строка 'abcd' - true; 'abdc' - false; 'abd' - false (так как d идет после c).
Искал что мог, не пойму что можно сделать.
Что посоветуете новичку?

Comment: [получаете](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) коды двух символов и проверяете, что отличаются они на единицу.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin для буквы «ё» не очень сработает

Comment: @andreymal в латинском алфавите раньше вроде бы не было такой буквы.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а в вопросе вроде не указано что алфавит строго латинский

Comment: @andreymal зато приведены два примера. и оба из латинских букв. логично предположить, что из всего множества существующих алфавитов (их то ли тысячи, то ли десятки тысяч, то ли сотни, и одни и те же символы нередко входят в разные алфавиты, а схожие алфавиты имеют разный порядок сортировки в разных языках, и всё это лишь добавляет проблем), автора вопроса интересует лишь латинский алфавит.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не логично, неопытные люди часто упускают нюансы, которые потом больно выстреливают в ногу на продакшене

Comment: @andreymal, предлагаю открыть курсы, посвящённые этой животрепещущей проблеме, и грести деньги лопатой.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я слишком альтруист и делюсь своими сверхценными знаниями бесплатно в комментариях на Stack Overflow 

Comment: Вам нужен абсолютно любой алфавит или конкретно английский или определённый набор алфавитов?

Comment: EzioMercer, в целом без разницы, я ведь могу использовать localeCompare. Первый комментарий помог очень сильно, спасибо @aleksandrbarakin